# Is there a way to separate continues plot mark for each candlesticks

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

Currently have this and it automatically connecting the plot if they are continues marks.

```
plot(stopLossPrice, color=color.rgb(255, 153, 0), title="Mark", linewidth=2, style=plot.style_steplinebr, offset=0)

if (not na(stopLossPrice))
    label.new(bar_index, stopLossPrice, text="SL - 2%", style=label.style_label_up, color=color.new(#00f708, 100), textcolor=color.rgb(255, 153, 0), size=size.small)
```

[image]

I tried this, but its thickness is not enough and its width is too short.

```
plotchar(series=buyPrice, char="——", color=color.rgb(0, 255, 0), title="Mark", offset=0, location=location.absolute)
```

Is there a way or other alternatives to separate continues plot mark for each candlesticks like this image:

[image]

Comment: As far as I am concerned that is unfortunately impossible as of now. Either you use plots with lines that are connected - unless you have na value for a candle and use steplinebr - or try lines / polylines that will have a different display effect too, so not really alternative for that.